# What color shoes can USSF referee's wear?

Tags: football, officiating

It states in the 2014 ATR:

> 5.1 Officiating Team Uniforms
>   .... Black shoes are preferred but
>   referees can wear any color shoes so long as they are appropriate to perform the duties
>   required of an official.....

However, I also read through other various web sites and heard from other refs that only black shoes are allowed and may have white logo/lettering on them.

So, what color shoes can the referee's wear and do they need to match the AR's?

Comment: Why don't you ask the other refs you're talking to where they're getting their information from?

Answer (score 1):

From the rule book:

> 5.1 REFEREE UNIFORM
>
> ... It is also occasionally important that players, who are frequently looking down at the ground, be able to identify the referee quickly by differences in the shoes. Accordingly, the referee’s shoes should be predominantly black, clean, polished, and neatly tied.

So yes, only black, none others. Obviously depends on the level of the referee and the level of game their officiating.

Comment: Good answer, even though the stated reason is nonsensical (players can also see socks and they are much easier to change the colour of; what happens if players all wear black boots as well?).